# Containerization of Node-Red failing: cannot find module 'express'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, node-red

I am very new to Docker.

I am getting an error saying "cannot find module 'express'" while trying to containerize simple node-red application. The details are as follows:

**Base machine**

- OS -Debian 9 (stretch) 64-bit
- RAM -8 gb
- GNOME - 3.22.2
- Env - Oracle Virtual Box

**Node-Red source**

- https://github.com/node-red/node-red.git

**Docker Version**

- 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

**docker-compose -v**

- 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b

**Docker File**

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

RUN useradd -c 'Node-Red user' -m -d /home/nodered -s /bin/bash nodered

RUN chown -R nodered.nodered /home/nodered

RUN echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://xxxx:yyyy";" >  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01turnkey  \
    && echo "Acquire::https::Proxy \"http://xxxx.yyyy";" >>  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01turnkey

ENV http_proxy="http://xxxx:yyyy \
    https_proxy="http://xxxx:yyyy"

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    sudo \
    git \
    python \
    make \
    g++ \
    gnupg2

RUN mkdir -p /home/nodered/shaan-node-red && chown -R nodered.nodered /home/nodered/shaan-node-red
ENV HOME /home/nodered/shaan-node-red
WORKDIR /home/nodered/shaan-node-red
RUN ls -la
RUN env

USER root

RUN echo "nodered ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/nodered && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/nodered


RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN rm -rf node-v9.x

RUN node -v (v9.9.0) && npm -v (5.6.0)

RUN npm config set proxy "http://xxxx:yyyy" \
    npm config set http-proxy "http://xxxx:yyyy"

COPY . /home/nodered/shaan-node-red


RUN cd /home/nodered/shaan-node-red && ls -la && npm install
RUN npm run build && ls -la


RUN cd /home/nodered/shaan-node-red/node_modules/ && git clone https://github.com/netsmarttech/node-red-contrib-s7.git && ls -la | grep s7 && cd ./node-red-contrib-s7 && npm install 
RUN ls -la /home/nodered/shaan-node-red/node_modules


ENTRYPOINT ["sh","entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

- node /home/nodered/shaan-node-red/red.js

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.0'

services:

 web:

  image: shaan-node-red

  build: .

  volumes:

   - .:/home/nodered/shaan-node-red

  ports:

   - "1880:1880"

   - "5858:5858"

  network_mode: host
```

**Building with command:**

```
docker-compose up
```

**Error description**

- [image: This is the error I am getting after successful docker-compose]

**Note**

Not getting any error while building same node-red at the base machine.

Comment: Any reason why you are building your own container and not using the ones provided by the Node-RED project?

Comment: Also have you tried starting a shell in the container and checking that the build actually created what you think it should?

Comment: I am building my own container as I need some customization without any modification of node-red repository code. As well as I need container debugging via VS Code.

Comment: I have tried to start a shell and it is very much successful. Even I have started the container that is created just after it is executed the last dockerfile command i.e **ENTRYPOINT ["sh","entrypoint.sh"]** in my case and inside shaan-node-red directory I did **node red.js**. It is starting node-red normally. Yea.. the extra nodes like s7 is not getting enabled but that is I believe is a different issue.

Comment: But `node red.js` is not what your entrypoint script is running...

Comment: Yes..I have used the absolute path only as entrypoint.sh script. Even I have tried using the following instead:  **ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/home/nodered/shaan-node-red/red.js"]**. No luck...the same error I am getting..Again, if it is the problem of entrypoint then the next container should not work properly. This issue is there in the final image.\

Comment: I meant more try cd'ing to the right drectoty first the running `node red.js` then node can find the `node_modules` directory

Comment: That also I have tried and got the same result..entrypoint.sh >> cd ~ and  then node red.js....again at the same directory node_modules are present (verified).